# Button inside jade table cell

Tags: javascript, html, pug

I want to add a button to shown in each row of the table, But the button does not appear cant figure out why. I'm new to jade and node js

> Jade file

```
html 
head
body 


table.table.table(border='1')
    thead
        tr 
        th ID 
        th Name
        th Age
        th City
        th Department
    tbody 
    each row in rows 
        tr 
            td=row.id
            td=row.name
            td=row.age
            td=row.city
            td=row.department
            td button(type='submit',onclick='edit("#{row.id}")') Edit

            script.
                function edit(d){
                var val = confirm ("Do you want to edit the record ?");
                if (val==true){
                return true;
                }
                };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not indenting your th's correctly (they need to be indented relative to the tr that they are in) and you need to include an empty one (or set a colspan = 2"on the last th) to accommodate the td that the edit button requires)

```
thead
    tr 
        th ID 
        th Name
        th Age
        th City
        th Department
        th
```